Can you lock individual nodes in Node-RED?
Is it possible to lock just an individual node in a flow. I know locking flows is possible. What I want to achieve is the node still functioning, but not being editable/removable from the board.

No
You can hide or disable a flow (tab) but that is a lowest level of granularity.

Ah, figured as much. It would be a nice feature to have, although I'm not sure if it will ever be taken into consideration / required by the community.
